# How can I change the decimal to a colon?

Tags: java, printf, double

> Without changing the code, how would I be able to change the output from being 13.00 to 13:00? Is it possible to do so in the printf string?

```
  System.out.print("Please enter the current hour on the clock(no minutes): ");
  double time = sc.nextDouble();

  System.out.print("Please enter the duration in hours: ");
  int duration = sc.nextInt();

  double newTime = (time+duration)-24;
  System.out.println();

  System.out.printf("If it is %.2f, in %d hours, it will be %.2f.\n",time,duration,newTime);
```

Comment: how can you change the output without changing the code? Modifying the printf string also changes the code

Comment: I don't know how to phrase it. I want to change it, but I don't want to add a new method other than printf or the use of variables.

Comment: What about converting the time to a string, then use replace something like this `newTime.toString().replace(".",":");` and you could do it all within the same line

Comment: Ummm ... if 13:00 is supposed to represent 13 hours 0 minutes, then you are going about this the wrong way.  Consider 13.50 as a floating point number of hours represents "half way between" 13:00 and 14:00.  But 13:50 (hours:minutes) is ten minutes before 14:00.  That conversion is incorrect .... unless you are proposing to bring back [metric time](http://hoaxes.org/af_database/permalink/metric_time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend replacing the "." to ":" as a stand-alone line. I don't see why you'd want to do that within the printf. Nonetheless, here is an example of how you could do it

```
System.out.printf("If it is %s.\n", String.valueOf(time).replace(".",":"));
```

Essentially converting the double to a string, then replacing the character.
Also, remember to change the %s tag.